# How to call a method of a parameterized type?

Tags: java, generics

Just jumping into Java Generics and I've run into a bit of a problem: I can't seem to invoke the method of a parameterized type:

```
class test 
{
    public static void main( String args[ ] )
    {    
        invoke_baz( new foo( ) );
    }
    public static < Type > void invoke_baz( Type object )
    {
        object.baz( );
    }   
    public static class foo
    {
        public void baz( )
        {   }
    }       
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5):

You've declared your generic type parameter `Type`, but it could be anything, not just a `foo`, such as a `String`.

Restrict `type` with an upper bound so that you know it's some kind of `foo`:

```
public static <Type extends foo> void invoke_baz( Type object )
```

Alternatively, just ask for a `foo` in your argument, removing any need for generics:

```
public static void invoke_baz(Foo object)
```

Comment: +1 For the suggestion to use polymorphism rather than generics

Comment: So in other words, Java Generics isn't so much a generic programming facility as it is "a little syntactic sugar" to relieve the user from having to make explicit casts in certain situations - got it! :) I guess I'll just have to rely on the good old fashioned "copy, paste, search, and replace" techniques I learned back when I was using C...

Comment: Generics in Java are for when a class (or a method) has a relationship with a specific yet unknown type.  Here the type is known: `foo`, so generics are unnecessary.

Comment: Right, but having to supply some sort of base class/interface/whatever pretty much mitigates the usefulness of Generics overall. I just can't help but wonder what the designers of the language were thinking when they decided to go the "type erasure" route rather than adopt the approach used by C++ compilers...

Comment: @SeaBass it may be less useful for certain purposes than C++ templates (which have their own set of problems) but still provides the benefit of compile time type checking when compared to using raw types.

Comment: @herman Like 0.1% as useful as what C++ what has to offer, actually. But okay, I understand the limitations now at least. Thanks for everyone's comments.

Comment: @SeaBass I see what you mean, but on the other hand in C++ it's impossible to specify that a type parameter must e.g. implement a certain interface, even if the template code only works correctly for those types.

Comment: @herman Not true - template specialization, SFINAE, and a host of other template metaprogramming techniques could be used in such situations. Anyway, in those rare cases where one really does need to restrict instantiation by type, the best approach would probably be to just use straight inheritance to begin with...

Comment: @SeaBass Straight inheritance?  Example: java.util.EnumMap restricts the keys to any (specific) Enum subtype:  `EnumMap<K extends Enum<K>, V> extends AbstractMap<K, V>`  What does straight inheritance mean in this example?

Comment: @herman Right, got carried away thinking C++! I stand corrected. :)

Answer (score 0):

Java is not duck typed, the type checker is not able to realize that the generic method is calling a method that is available on the object you are then passing to the method. It must correctly check that generic code regardless of your specific case.

You need to fullfil this by explicitly declaring the type variable is restricted to a certain hierarchy of classes so that the type checker can make assumptions on it:

```
interface Bazzable {
  public void baz();
}

public <Type extends Bazzable> void invoke(Type object) {
  object.baz();
}

public class Foo implements Bazzable {
  public void baz() {
    System.out.println("baz");
  }
}
```

In this way you specify that the type variable is at least a `Bazzable` so you will be restricted to pass only certain types to the method but on the other side you will be able to call any method that is specified in `Bazzable`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because it's a generic -- type type isn't known at compile time. Compiler didn't know what the type was -- nor do you. One approach is to do a runtime cast. You first need to decide what type you'd expect, and you can do something like this:

```
public static < Type > void invoke_baz( Type object )
{
    SomeClass someClass = (SomeClass) object;
    someClass.baz();
}
```

This would ofcourse produce cast error if provided object / type isn't of type `SomeClass`.

Better approach would be to declare an interface that ensure contracts of your method, eg:

```
public interface HaveBaz {
  baz();
}
```

And request subtype of that interface on your generic method declaration

```
public static < Type extends HaveBaz > void invoke_baz( Type object )
{
  object.baz();
}
```